# UINavigationController inside UIPopoverController - in iOS 7 navigation bar behind other views

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I included a navigation controller within a popover. The view includes an image that I would like partially covered. In iOS6 is behind the navigation bar, in ios7 exactly the opposite. Attaching the Screenshot.
Does anyone know why?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autolayout constraints: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Or try this (no elegant solution):

```
NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
float ver_float = [ver floatValue];

if (ver_float >= 7.0f)
{
   CGRect frame = self.myView.frame;
   frame.origin.y = self.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
   [self.myView setFrame:frame]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the navigation bar translucent, you can try navigationBar.isTranslucent = NO.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, layout by default extends the the edges of the container.  This is controller by the `edgesForExtendedLayout` view controller property.  If you want the layout to start with the top aligned with the navigation bar, you need to disable it by setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout`.

For example:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // layout with top of view starting at bottom of navigation bar
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        // continue with init

    }
 }
```